# Android SDK cannot be found after every gradle sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I have been facing this issue for 2 days that Android SDK cannot be found after I sync the gradle files, I have to close project and remove from the recent projects and re-open it, I don't remember what I updated or what I changed recently.

And yes, I have already tried invalidate caches and restart, clearing gradle cache etc.

**System Specs:**

*Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.5*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your android studio window where it says SDK not found? It can be do some help here.

Comment: Here it is, https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNF9u.png

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from "Project Structure | Project"?

Answer (score 0):

First rebuild the app. might this has a good result
And remember don't use many countries IP like Iran because Android Studio Boycott this country. And thus connect to Vpn and Then Clean And Build project.
this ways might help you